# Use custom fields in index.php template file

Tags: php, custom-field, com-content

For some reason i need tu use **articles custom fields** in index.php file template, i try this code without success :

```
This after defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/models', 'ContentModel');

$id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('id');

$model =& JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request'=>true));
$appParams = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
$model->setState('params', $appParams);
$item =& $model->getItem($id);
$jcFields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article',  $item, True);

<?php if (!empty(($this->item->jcfields[5]->value))) {
   echo " background";
} ?>
```

Comment: I ran your code inside my template's index.php and it worked ok. $jcFields got the custom fields data which I'd set up on my article. I'm not sure why you're subsequently referencing $this->item->jcfields - did you explicitly set that up? Did you trying doing var_dump($jcFields) after you set it? (note that you have a capital F in jcFields).

Comment: OK thanks i need to see that.

Answer (score 0):

I debug your code and your `$jcFields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article',  $item, True);` is an empty array.

however, your `$item =& $model->getItem($id)` shows all the items of the article so the problem lies in `$jcFields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article',  $item, True);` but i don't know exactly why. I have tried several solutions but no success. Perhaps we could wait for someone with more experience to give us a better solution.

Comment: Thanks but it is articles custom fields and no template fields.

Comment: Oh that's tricky...let me try to find a solution.

Comment: Does it show any error?

Comment: Nothing, thanks.

Comment: Your last edited code create a 404 error.

Comment: Ok give me a minute.

Comment: No problems, thanks.

Comment: Do you have the error set to maximum?

Comment: Yes i set it to maximum, error 404

Comment: Try to `print_r` your `$JcFields` `print_R($jcFields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article',  $item, True));` and see the result you get

Comment: I can't see nothing because of the 404 error page

Comment: Use your code and try to `print_r($item = $model->getItem($id));`

Comment: What field do you want to show?

Comment: The field with id 5

Comment: The problem is that `$this->item` is not being recognized but it's according to the docs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106607/discussion-between-thiago-guimaraes-and-laurent).

Answer (score 0):

For each article the fields values can vary depending on the inputs you gave and just `$jcfield` data is enough for you to get the desired custom field. The data you receive will be in array format based on number of custom fields you have. Suppose you have several custom fields and you want to access data of a particular custom field to be used in a template then you iterate all the likely fields and get data according to the id:

```
foreach($jcFields as $field){
    if($field->id == 5){
        echo $field->value;
        }
}
```